# How to submit a form using PUT http verb in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, rest, http

I know that this question may have been made but I just can't get it to work. if someone could help me I would be very grateful. I have colletive/form installed but the answer can be an html form tag too.

Now listing my form, my route and my exception.

```
{{ Form::model( array('route' => array('casas.update', 238), 'method' => 'PUT')) }}
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
```

-

```
Route::resource('casas', 'CasasController');
```

exception: 
 MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

Comment: what request did you make? was your route `casas/1` (or another id)?

Comment: you do not need Put you can do a simple `post`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With plain html / blade

```html
<form action="{{ route('casas.update', $casa->id) }}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('put') }}

    {{-- Your form fields go here --}}

    <input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

Wirth Laravel Collective it may look like

```
{{ Form::model($casa, ['route' => ['casas.update', $casa->id], 'method' => 'put']) }}
    {{-- Your form fields go here --}}

    {{ Form::submit('Update') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

In both cases it's assumed that you pass a model instance `$casa` into your blade template

In your controller

```php
class CasasController extends Controller
{
    public function edit(Casa $casa) // type hint your Model
    {
        return view('casas.edit')
            ->with('casa', $casa);
    }

    public function update(Request $request, Casa $casa) // type hint your Model
    {
        dd($casa, $request->all());
    }
}
```