# Changing laravel form to html form

Tags: laravel, forms, laravel-blade

Hi i created a form with laravel form helpers but i want to change it to a standard html form. The issue i am having is with the "PUT" function, when i try to edit my posts no data is displayed so i think my form properties are wrong.

Form header

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('posts.update',[$post->id])}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{csrf_field()}}
{{method_field('put')}}

<input type=""text" name="name" class="name">
<input type=""text" name="body" class="body">
<button></button>
</form>
```

(--UPDATED--)

Laravel Form

```
{!! Form::model($post, ['route' => ['posts.update', $post->id], 'method' => 'PUT']) !!}

            {{ Form::label('name', 'Name:') }}
            {{ Form::text('name', null, ["class" => 'form-control input-lg']) }}
{ Form::label('body', 'Body:') }}
            {{ Form::text('body', null, ["class" => 'form-control input-lg']) }}
{{ Form::submit('Save Changes', array('class' => 'btn btn-success btn-block')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

I want the blog data to be displayed in the form for me to edit.. When i use form helpers it works fine

Any help will be much appreciated

Thanks

Ash

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to submit a form using PUT http verb in Laravel 5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864942/how-to-submit-a-form-using-put-http-verb-in-laravel-5-3)

Comment: doesn't work thanks for your response though

Comment: {!! Form::model($post, ['route' => ['posts.update', $post->id], 'method' => 'PUT']) !!} this is the only way i can get it to work but i want standard html forms

Comment: its because that you are not populating the values  ```<input type=""text" name="name" class="name" value = {{$post->name}}>```

Answer (score 0):

Ash,

I don't see the Laravel form code here to compare the two, but the easiest way to convert the Laravel form to straight HTML is to view source on the generated form and copy the generated HTML code back into the blade. Then you can replace populated data with variables.

(--UPDATED--)

Hence, put this back into your blade:

```
{!! Form::model($post, ['route' => ['posts.update', $post->id], 'method' => 'PUT']) !!}

{{ Form::label('name', 'Name:') }}
{{ Form::text('name', null, ["class" => 'form-control input-lg']) }}
{ Form::label('body', 'Body:') }}
{{ Form::text('body', null, ["class" => 'form-control input-lg']) }}
{{ Form::submit('Save Changes', array('class' => 'btn btn-success btn-block')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

and then copy the HTML output for the "put" action. Or, if you're on the current version of Laravel, you can simply use the put method as follows:

`@method('PUT')`

(see https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade)

(--ORIGINAL--)
Also, you didn't mention what version of Laravel you're on. The syntax for inserting fields into the blade varies.

(--UPDATED--)
@kapitan, you're right. I "learned" that from using LaraShift telling me that all my {{ $field }} needed to be changed to {!! $field !!} to upgrade my app. The syntax has changed as follows.

In older versions of Laravel, variables inserted with {{ $field }} were UNescaped, and variables inserted with {{{ $field }}} were escaped.

In newer versions of Laravel, variables inserted with {{ $field }} are escaped, and variables inserted with {!! $field !!} are UNescaped. So the meaning of {{ $field }} has reversed from older versions to newer versions.

Comment: can you please give the reference where old version uses `{{ }}` and new version uses `{!! !!}` because as per official [documentation of 5.8](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade), it advises to use `{{}}` to prevent XSS attacks, thank you very much!

Comment: Hi thanks for your response i have updated my post please let me know your thoughts